# Fortran: How to store value 255 into one byte?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I would like to call a C api function from Fortran. The C function accepts an array of bytes:

```
void image(const void *bitmap, int w, int h);
```

where three successive bytes in `*bitmap` represent an RGB colour tripple and are interpreted as `unsigned char` in C. I want to initialize the bitmap in Fortran and take care of drawing inside C. Current definition in Fortran uses

```
integer*1 rgbImage(6,2)
```

to initialize an image of 2x2 for example, but compiler won't accept assignment

```
rgbImage(1,1) = 255
```

to get red colour. I've seen hints of using `BYTE`, `UNSIGNED*1`, `LOGICAL*1` for unsigned single bytes, but gfortran (MacPort's gcc 4.4 or 4.6 under Mac OS X) isn't really happy with either of them. I could probably get away by cheating and assigning value `-1` instead of `255`, but that is very uncomfortable to use. The compiler flag `-fno-range-check` helped compile the code, but might not be available in other Fortran compilers and I consider it an ugly solution (I would still want to catch other warning). The values `'FF'X` or `'11111111'B` are also recognized as 32-bit integers.

It is highly desirable for the code to be portable across different Fortran compilers.

Comment: Standard Fortran does not support unsigned integer types. Even in `ISO_C_BIDNING` there are no kinds that correspond to unsigned integers in C (except for `C_SIZE_T` and `C_INTPTR_T` but they are still treated as signed in Fortran). Some compilers provide unsigned types as an extension to the language. So you have to resort to something like using `ACHAR()` as pointed by Jonathan Dursi.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use `CHARACTER` variables, and use `ACHAR` to set values (and `ICHAR` to convert back to integers as necessary).   That should get you what you want and be completely portable.   eg,

```
character, dimension(6,2) :: rgbImage

rgbImage(1,1) = achar(255)
```

***Updated to add***:  if you're going to use the Fortran 2003 iso_c_binding stuff to interface to the C routines (highly recommended!) then you might as well make that rgbImage array characters of kind `c_char`, eg

```
character(kind=c_char), dimension(6,2) :: rgbImage
integer(kind=c_int) :: w, h

...
rgbImage(1,1) = achar(255)
...

call image(rgbImage, w, h)
```

where you've defined the interface for the routine

```
 interface
    subroutine image(img, w, h) bind(C)
       use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
       implicit none
       integer(kind=c_int), intent(in), value :: w, h
       character(kind=c_char) :: img(:,:)
    end subroutine image
 end interface
```

Comment: Alternative types are C_INT8_T (Fortran, ISO_C_Binding) and int8_t (C).  One could "cheat" and use uint8_t on the C side even though it doesn't formally match C_INT8_T.   Another possible approach...

Comment: `achar(x)` will cause a warning during compilation if `x>127`. We are dealing with RGB color format here, which means values of `x` from 128 to 255 will occur quite often. Even though the warning seems harmless, it is better to use `char(x)` to set values in color components.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative strategy that may be suitable for some circumstances is to pass the 1 byte c int array to an Integer(1) array, say, iVal(:), then create another Int array such as Integer(2)  iVal2(:), then:

```
Where(iVal(:) < 0)
    iVal2(:) = -iVal(:)+127
ElseWhere
    iVal2(:) = iVal(:)
End Where
```

... this can be a bit more efficient/cleaner compared to converting to/fro chars (sometimes) and requires less coding (sometimes).

If you do a lot of this type of thing (interfacing various types of usigned's etc  to Fortran), a few utility routines relying on Fortran's bit intrinsics may be a worthwhile investment (e.g. BTest(), iBSet() etc).